# Can't install Mediatek MT7630E driver. Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am trying to install Mediatek MT7630E driver https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E,

When I try, I get this:

```
smith @ Smith-PCt: / media / smith / Socrates / Linux / MT7630E-release $ sudo chmod + x install
[sudo] password for smith:
smith @ Smith-PCt: / media / smith / Socrates / Linux / MT7630E-release $ sudo ./install
./install: line 10: make: command not found
smith @ Smith-PCt: / media / smith / Socrates / Linux / MT7630E-release $
```

How can I resolve this?

I tried the solution in the answer and I entered the code: 
`sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic`

and got the answer:

```
smith@Smith-PCt:~$ sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic
[sudo] password for smith: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0
  libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0
  linux-headers-4.15.0-45 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic linux-libc-dev make
  manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  menu debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg
  gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib
  gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg
  libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg
  libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc libstdc++-7-doc make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dkms dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libfakeroot
  libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0
  libubsan0 linux-headers-4.15.0-45 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 39.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 207 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-45.48
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasan4 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libubsan0 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcilkrts5 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmpx2 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgcc-7-dev amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libstdc++-7-dev amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 g++-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 make amd64 4.1-9.1ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dpkg-dev all 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 build-essential amd64 12.4ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dkms all 2.3-3ubuntu9.2
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libfakeroot amd64 1.22-2ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 fakeroot amd64 1.22-2ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.03-1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-5
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-3
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-45 all 4.15.0-45.48
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic amd64 4.15.0-45.48
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.15.0.45.47
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 manpages-dev all 4.15-1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-45.48_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libitm1_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libatomic1_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libasan4_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/liblsan0_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libtsan0_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libubsan0_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libcilkrts5_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libmpx2_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-8/libquadmath0_8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/g++-7_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/g++_7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/build-essential/build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-diff-perl/libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-5_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libalgorithm-merge-perl/libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.15.0-45_4.15.0-45.48_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.45.47_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
smith@Smith-PCt:~$
```

What do I need to do? What would it work?

Comment: Did you have a reliable internet connection at the time? What does this tell us? `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Installation

You need kernel headers to build the driver

As an example, on Debian and derivatives, assuming you're on an amd64 system:

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic
```

That's all for dependencies.

First give some file execution permission:

```
chmod +x install test uninstall bpatch
```

Now to install it, run:

```
./install
```

To test it without installing, run:

```
./test
```

To uninstall, run:

```
./uninstall
```

To install with dkms:

```
sudo make dkms
```

The driver will automatically load at startup...

[SOURCE](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/blob/release/README.md#installation)

Comment: For Ubuntu use `sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic`

Comment: @Jeremy31 edited the command. Thanks.

Comment: Try to disabled secure boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

- Using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS with Mediatek MT7630e wifi adapter
- Worked out of the box, so the correct driver comes with the iso load
- Did the usual updating of packages after install and on reboot wifi
  was no longer working
- Tried multiple proposed solutions out on the web to try to fix the
  problem and none worked,  so went to plan B
- Decided to do a live usb boot of KDE Neon to see if it starts with
  wifi out of the box and it did
- Rebooted into Kubunutu and wireless worked again, rebooted a few
  times, and wireless continued to work, SO PROBLEM SOLVED

Wanted to understand what and where the driver is on the hard drive in case this happens again with future updates, so ran the following commands:

- sudo lspci    (determines the name of the wifi adapter - result
  03:00.0 MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter)
- sudo lspci -vv -s 03:00.0    (determines the name of the driver that
  kernel is using - result Kernel driver in use: mt76x0e,   Kernel
  module: mt76x0e)
- sudo modinfo mt76x0e    (determines where the driver is installed on
  the harddrive - result 
  /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/mt76x0e.ko)
- Saved a copy in another folder in case it happens again but it
  appears rebooting to a live usb solves the problem.